# How to pass coordinates from inside a function to a variables and then add them outside the function to another variable

Tags: javascript, api, coordinates, weather, weather-api

edit1: removed the var from lan and lon under the showPosition function.

I am trying to obtain the coordinates of my current location.
Get those coordinates and pass them through a function.
After passing the coordinates I want to save them to variable lan and lon.
Use those coordinates to add them to a url variable.
From there I want to use that url variable to parse and use JSON to find name, city, etc.

HTML:

```
  <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

  <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
  <p id="geoLocal"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var lon, lan;
 var geoLocal = document.getElementById("geoLocal");

 //First part, I am creating the function to get the coordinates. 
 function getLocation() {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
 } else {
     geoLocal.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
};
 //The first lines of code outputs the function and tells me the coordinates. 
 //As it tells me these coordinates I want to save them to **lan** **and** lon variables. 

 function showPosition(position) {
 geoLocal.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
 "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
 lan= position.coords.latitude;
 lon= position.coords.longitude;
 console.log(lan, lon);
 return (lan, lon);

 };
```

Above I would want it to return the lan and lon variable coordinates so I can add them to the URL below:

I wand to add the lan and lon and add them to the end of wUndergroundGeo below.
Right now the  coordinates are added, but essentially the url/variable will be

```
 var baseURL="http://api.wunderground.com/api/8a8af55ae16c8627/geolookup/q/"
 var addLanLon= baseURL+ lan + "," + lon; 
 var wUndergroundGeo=addLanLon;
```

the wUndergroundGeo will replace the same variable below.

```
 var wUndergroundGeo='http://api.wunderground.com/api/8a8af55ae16c8627/geolookup/q/34.4278,-119.7034111.json';
 var wUndergroundSF= 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/8a8af55ae16c8627/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json'
 var weather= new XMLHttpRequest();
 weather.open("GET",wUndergroundGeo, false);
 weather.send(null);

 var myRequest= JSON.parse(weather.response);
 var cityLocal= "City location: "+ myRequest.location.city + "<br/>";
 document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML= cityLocal
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? when are you going to call the api?

Comment: At first glance you're shadowing your global vars by redeclaring them in your `showPosition` function.

Comment: The outcome I am looking for is to obtain the coordinates and save them to variables that I can use later @CarlEdwards.

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni I believe I can get it out to the API, I am just stuck in saving the coordinates for longitude and latitude.

Comment: Change `var lan` and `var lon` by just `lan` and `lon` in your function `showPosition`. Javascript closure should do the trick for you.

Comment: By redeclaring `lan` and `lon` in your `showPosition` function, you shadow the global variables you declared initially. Try removing the `var` keyword from the variables in the function. Then after the function is invoked, the values should be accessible from those variables.

Comment: I'm sure you can get it out ot the API @GauchoRoger, but I'm not a psychic, and I don't know how you plan to get the `lan` and `lon` to the api. 
`return (lan, lon);` will not return an array, if that's what you ar expecting, `return [lan, lon];` will.
 Good luck finding a solution.

Comment: Updated the var for lan and lon and console.log after outside the function and I am getting underfined.

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni I will be adding the coordinates in lan an lon to the url so the API will be complete.

Comment: sorry if my question bother you, I'm just trying to understand what you want to do, and how you want to accomplish it, and I still don't understand if you are going to declare a new function, to create the url inside the `showPosition` function, or what you are expecting.  
 Removing the `var`, from the variables in the function, will make javascript assing the value to the global variables.  
The return won't work, and I don't see a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work. I moved the rest of my code lines inside the show position function.

```
 var lon, lan;
   var example='http://api.wunderground.com/api/8a8af55ae16c8627/geolookup/q/34.4277882,-119.7034209.json'; //Examples of completed coordinates
 var exampleCity="http://api.wunderground.com/api/8a8af55ae16c8627/conditions/q/CA/Santa_Barbara.json"; //example City.
 var geoLocal = document.getElementById("geoLocal");
 var temp= document.getElementById("temp");
 $(document).ready(function(){

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
 } else {
  geoLocal.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
function showPosition(position) {
var beforeURL= 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/8a8af55ae16c8627/';
var conditionsURL="conditions/q/";
var geoLookUp="geolookup/q/"
var endURL=".json";
geoLocal.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
lan= position.coords.latitude;
lon= position.coords.longitude;
wUndergroundGeo=beforeURL + geoLookUp+ lan + "," + lon + endURL;
// return (position);
```

`

```
 var wUndergroundSF= 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/8a8af55ae16c8627/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json'
 // var wUndergroundGeo= 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/8a8af55ae16c8627/geolookup/q/34.4278,-119.7034111.json';
 var weather= new XMLHttpRequest();
 weather.open("GET",wUndergroundGeo, false);
 weather.send(null);

 var myRequest= JSON.parse(weather.response);
 var cityLocal= "City location: "+ myRequest.location.city + "<br/>";
 document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML= cityLocal
 var stateURL= myRequest.location.state + "/";

 var cityURL=myRequest.location.city ;
 var cityURL=cityURL.replace(/ /gi,"_");//Replaces spaces of city with "_" so url will be valid.


 var weatherURL= beforeURL + conditionsURL +stateURL + cityURL + endURL;
 console.log("Weather", weatherURL)

 var weather2= new XMLHttpRequest();
 weather2.open("GET", weatherURL, false);
 weather2.send(null);

 var secRequest=JSON.parse(weather2.response);
 var fTemp= "Fahrenheit: " + secRequest.current_observation.temp_f;
 console.log(fTemp);
```

temp.innerHTML=fTemp;
      return fTemp;